# Changing styles of day numbers in react-datepicker by Hacker0x01

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I have react-datepicker installed in my project, it has its custom styles, and I can't figure out how to change the styles of the inner elements. So, now, the background-color of day numbers is blue, I want it to be different color, how?
I went looking for the source code in web dev tools, which pointed me to the generated code done by the library, then to similar code in node_modules/react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css
and to node_modules/react-datepicker/src/stylesheets/datepicker.scss

but my attempts at changing anything did not provide positive result.
Any ideas would be welcome.